# IF EXISTS Receiving Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following SQL cmd but am receiving ERROR 1064 (42000):

`IF EXISTS(select 1 from namelist WHERE user='smitht' AND name='Tom Smith') BEGIN PRINT 'yes' END;`

I've tested the select statement on its own and it works, so I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Its an MYSQL database and the error is the following ERROR 1064 (42000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you use IF EXISTS in MYSQL. You may try this:

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(
             SELECT *
             from namelist WHERE user='smitht' AND name='Tom Smith'))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the document you can't use `IF` statement like that, but you can use `IF` function:

```
SELECT IF (EXISTS(
          select 1 from namelist WHERE user='smitht' AND name='Tom Smith'), 'yes', '')
```